# Thread sanitizer complaining of unexpected memory map

Tags: parallel-processing, linux-kernel, g++, compiler-specific

I am trying to test the usage of -fsanitize=thread for gcc, and its complaining of unexpected memory mapping, maybe there might have been some change in the kernel, and thats the reason for it. Is there any thing I could do to make it work ?

This is what I am doing ...

```
mfrw@kp ...fpp/asgn/as2 % 
mfrw@kp ...fpp/asgn/as2 % cat tiny.cpp 
#include <pthread.h>
int global;
void *thread(void *x) {
        global = 42;
        return x;
}
int main() {
        pthread_t t;
        pthread_create(&t, NULL, thread, NULL);
        global = 43;
        pthread_join(t, NULL);
        return global;
}
mfrw@kp ...fpp/asgn/as2 % g++ tiny.cpp -fsanitize=thread -pie -fPIC -g -O1 -o tinyrace -pthread
mfrw@kp ...fpp/asgn/as2 % uname -a
Linux kp 4.4.33-1-MANJARO #1 SMP PREEMPT Fri Nov 18 18:06:44 UTC 2016 x86_64 GNU/Linux
mfrw@kp ...fpp/asgn/as2 % gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 6.2.1 20160830
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

mfrw@kp ...fpp/asgn/as2 % ./tinyrace 
FATAL: ThreadSanitizer: unexpected memory mapping 0x55e38776b000-0x55e38776c000
mfrw@kp ...fpp/asgn/as2 %
```

Comment: Got the same trash at the moment.  Looking for solution as well.

Comment: for me, it worked with an older kernel... I had an ancient server with kernel 2.6.32, so maybe its something with the kernel

Comment: Same issue: Ubuntu 17.04 ; kernel ver 4.10.0-33-generic ; gcc 6.3.0 . 
Not using '-pie -fPIC' does not solve the problem.  Awaiting an answer..

Answer (score 1):

It is to do with your compilation option:  *-pie -fPIC*.

If I compiled your code (in Ubuntu 16.04, latest update) with:

*g++ -fsanitize=thread -pie -fPIC tinyrace.c -g -O1 -o tinyrace -pthread*

I will get the same error.

But if changed to:

*g++ -fsanitize=thread tinyrace.c -g -O1 -o tinyrace -pthread*

Then the race condition alert is printed:

```
./tinyrace 
==================
WARNING: ThreadSanitizer: data race (pid=12032)
  Write of size 4 at 0x00000060108c by thread T1:
    #0 thread(void*) /home/tteikhua/tinyrace.c:5 (tinyrace+0x000000400a5d)
    #1 <null> <null> (libtsan.so.0+0x0000000230d9)

  Previous write of size 4 at 0x00000060108c by main thread:
    #0 main /home/tteikhua/tinyrace.c:11 (tinyrace+0x000000400ab1)

  Location is global 'global' of size 4 at 0x00000060108c (tinyrace+0x00000060108c)

  Thread T1 (tid=12034, running) created by main thread at:
    #0 pthread_create <null> (libtsan.so.0+0x000000027577)
    #1 main /home/tteikhua/tinyrace.c:10 (tinyrace+0x000000400aa7)

SUMMARY: ThreadSanitizer: data race /home/tteikhua/tinyrace.c:5 thread(void*)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's due to changes in the kernel and it's not GCC-specific, clang exposes the same behaviour.

There is a corresponding [bug in GCC tracker](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=67308), which references [fix in the upstream](https://llvm.org/viewvc/llvm-project?view=revision&revision=282152). Comments mention kernels 4.1+, but I hit this problem on 3.16.

As mentioned in the answer by Peter Teoh, it might work if you omit pie/pic options, but the proper fix is in newer thread sanitizer used by newer compilers (after September 2016, but it's not clear whether GCC 6.x branch got the fix).